# Passing data to an ionic 3 Component is not working

Tags: angular, components, ionic3

I have been working with the Conference template and noticed that the side menu is quite duplicated in the code of the app.template.html.  As a better practice, I thought a component should be created and am working to learn that for myself.  While I can create the component, my data is not getting passed.

I moved the PageInterface into an interface class to export and import in different places.

```
export interface PageInterface {
    title: string;
    name: string;
    component: any;
    icon: string;
    logsOut?: boolean;
    index?: number;
    tabName?: string;
    tabComponent?: any;
}
```

My component side-menu-list.ts, which is called as the console.log output is present.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PageInterface } from '../../interfaces/page-interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'side-menu-list',
    templateUrl: 'side-menu-list.html'
})
export class SideMenuListComponent {

    @Input() Heading: string = "Place Holder";
//    @Input() SideMenuItemList: PageInterface[];

    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello SideMenuListComponent Component');
    }
}
```

The component HTML:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>Passed: {{Heading}}</ion-list-header>
<!-- 
    <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let SideMenuItem of SideMenuItemList" (click)="OpenPage(SideMenuItem)">
          <ion-icon item-start [name]="SideMenuItem.icon" [color]="IsActive(SideMenuItem)"></ion-icon>
          {{SideMenuItem.title}}
    </button> 
-->
</ion-list>
```

I temporarily commented out the button to just try to get the Heading to work.

The call now from  app.component.html

```
<side-menu-list [Heading]="Testing"></side-menu-list>
```

The other menu options still use:

```
        <ion-list>
            <ion-list-header>Account</ion-list-header>
            <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of loggedOutPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
                <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon" [color]="isActive(p)"></ion-icon>
                {{p.title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
```

I am looking to pass a second parameter to side-menu-list as:

```
<side-menu-list [Heading]="Testing" MenuOptions=loggedOutPages></side-menu-list>
```

when this is working.

Comment: You should stick to using lowercase for class properties. ie. Heading/SideMenuItemList should begin lowercase. Don't you have to inport @Input too? There's a bit more to the menus as well. The id is being used with a MenuController instance menu with an enable method. The ion-nav references #content and that is used in an attribute on the <ion-menu [content]="content">

Comment: Case style is to distinguish our variables from  built in and external libraries, but I can change it for the test.  Input is imported in the first line with Component.